# UICollectionView displays items incorrectly when adding items to sections (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My UICollectionview works fine when I add items to Section 1, and changing the section of an item from section 1 to section 2 works. However, the items start displaying incorrectly if I do the following:

1. Add items to Section 1
2. Move item from section 1 to section 2
3. Add new item to Section 1 (<--> here the data breaks and the collection view starts displaying one item twice)

I'll refer to this as the "Breakdown Scenario" below.

I have been struggling with understanding the reason for this problem for a few days now. I am sure it is something basic, but at my current level of knowledge I have not been able to figure it out. I'm fine implementing UICollectionviews with one section, but I relied on the Raywenderlich tutorial on UICollectionViews for figuring out how to implement multiple sections, and I don't feel entirely at home with the sample code. The tutorial I relied on is here (though I think behind a paywall): (https://www.raywenderlich.com/6308-beginning-collection-views/lessons/16).

Here's the description of how the UICollectionview works in my app, and the key bits of code.

---

When the app is loaded, a function in datasource.swift runs a function that populates the UICollectionview.

This is the code:

```
    private func loadPicturesFromDisk() -> [Picture] {
    sections.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("pictures").appendingPathExtension("plist")
    let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()

    if let retrievedPicturesData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL), let decodedPictures = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Picture>.self, from: retrievedPicturesData) {
        for picture in decodedPictures {
            let pictureName = picture.pictureName
            print("The pictureName in loadPicturesFromDisk = \(pictureName), the pictureCategory is = \(picture.pictureCategory)")
            let pictureCategory = picture.pictureCategory


            if !sections.contains(pictureCategory) {
                sections.append(pictureCategory)
            }

            let newPicture = Picture(picture: pictureName, category: pictureCategory)
            pictures.append(newPicture)

        }

        print("Enumerating through pictures in loadPicturesFromDisk")
        enumerateThroughPictures(pictures: pictures)


        return pictures

    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

This works as intended. I have a couple of print functions there to check that the data loaded looks right.

Now when the UICollectionView calls this data in cellForItemAt in the normal scenario, it works fine. However, in the Breakdown Scenario (as defined above) the data is not in sync with the data in the datasource array variables. Here is an example of how the data looks like when loaded, and when called by cellForItemAt in the Breakdown Scenario:

Data when checked when loading

```
Item(0: 1825 - No Category - indexPath = [0, 0] -      absoluteindexpath = 0
Item(1: 3630 - Filed - indexPath = [1, 0] -   absoluteindexpath = 3
Item(2: 8946 - No Category - indexPath = [0, 1] -   absoluteindexpath = 1
Item(3: 696 - No Category - indexPath = [0, 2] -   absoluteindexpath = 2
```

Data when checked at cellForItemAt:
    cellForItemAt is processing picture: 1825 - No Category,    with indexPath of [0, 0] and absoluteindexpath of 0
    cellForItemAt is processing picture: 3630 - Filed, with   indexPath of [0, 1] and absoluteindexpath of 1
    cellForItemAt is processing picture: 8946 - No Category, with indexPath of [0, 2] and absoluteindexpath of 2
    cellForItemAt is processing picture: 3630 - Filed, with indexPath of [1, 0] and absoluteindexpath of 3

Here is the code for cellForItemAt:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PicAppCollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1

    // create a temporary picture object used to populate the view


    if let picture = dataSource.pictureForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        print("cellForItemAt is processing picture: \(picture.pictureName) - \(picture.pictureCategory), with indexPath of \(indexPath) and absoluteindexpath of \(dataSource.absoluteIndexForIndexPath(indexPath))")
        if debuggingMode == true {
            cell.photoIDLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.photoIDLabel.text = picture.pictureName
        }

        cell.imageView.image = getSavedImage(named: picture.pictureName)
        cell.isEditing = isEditing

    } else {
        print("did not find an image for indexpath: \(indexPath)")
    }

    return cell
}
```

I use a UICollectionViewController, which relies heavily on dataSource.swift derived from the RW tutorial. I have replicated all of the data source code below as there are a lot of interdependencies in the function call.

```
class DataSource {
private var pictures = [Picture]()
//private var immutablePictures = [Picture]()
private var sections : [String] = []

private var latestPictureID = 0

var count: Int {
    return pictures.count
}

var numberOfSections: Int {
    return sections.count
}

// MARK:- Public
init() {
    // add init code if needed
    pictures = loadPicturesFromDisk()
}

func newPicture(newPicture: Picture) -> IndexPath {

    for picture in pictures {
        if picture.pictureName == newPicture.pictureName {
            let randomName = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10000)
            newPicture.pictureName = String(randomName)
        }
    }
    pictures.append(newPicture)
    print("The pictureName of the saved picture = \(newPicture.pictureName)")
    saveToFile(pictures: pictures)
    print("Launching array enumeration from newPicture before sort")
    enumerateThroughPictures(pictures: pictures)
    pictures.sort { $0.pictureCategory < $1.pictureCategory }
    print("Launching array enumeration from newPicture after sort sort")
    enumerateThroughPictures(pictures: pictures)
    return indexPathForPicture(newPicture)

}

func replacePictureAtIndexPath(picture: Picture, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // make this update the collectionview and maybe it works

    pictures[absoluteIndexForIndexPath(indexPath)] = picture
    let pictureCategory = picture.pictureCategory

    if !sections.contains(pictureCategory) {
        sections.append(pictureCategory)
    }
    saveToFile(pictures: pictures)
    print("Launching array enumeration from replacePictureAtIndexPath")
    enumerateThroughPictures(pictures: pictures)
    //pictures.sort { $0.pictureCategory < $1.pictureCategory }
}

func enumerateThroughPictures(pictures: [Picture]) {
    print("Enumerating through pictures.array:")
    var index = 0
    for picture in pictures {
        print("Item(\(index): \(picture.pictureName) - \(picture.pictureCategory) - indexPath = \(indexPathForPicture(picture)) - absoluteindexpath = \(absoluteIndexForIndexPath(indexPathForPicture(picture)))")
        index += 1
    }
}

func deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    var indexes = [Int]()
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        indexes.append(absoluteIndexForIndexPath(indexPath))
    }
    var newPictures = [Picture]()
    for (index, picture) in pictures.enumerated() {
        if !indexes.contains(index) {
            newPictures.append(picture)
        }
    }
    pictures = newPictures
}

func movePictureAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath, toIndexPath newIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == newIndexPath {
        print("Returning from movePicture as indexPath and newIndexPath were the same")
        return
    }
    let index = absoluteIndexForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let currentPicture = pictures[index]
    currentPicture.pictureCategory = sections[newIndexPath.section]
    let newIndex = absoluteIndexForIndexPath(newIndexPath)
    print("About to remove picture at : \(index)")

    pictures.remove(at: index)
    print("About to add picture at : \(newIndex)")
    pictures.insert(currentPicture, at: newIndex)
}

func indexPathForPicture(_ picture: Picture) -> IndexPath {
    let section = sections.index(of: picture.pictureCategory)!
    var item = 0
    for (index, currentPicture) in picturesForSection(section).enumerated() {
        if currentPicture === picture {
            item = index
            break
        }
    }
    return IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
}

func numberOfPicturesInSection(_ index: Int) -> Int {
    let currentPictures = picturesForSection(index)
    return currentPictures.count
}

func pictureForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Picture? {
    if indexPath.section > 0 {
        let currentPictures = picturesForSection(indexPath.section)
        return currentPictures[indexPath.item]
    } else {
        return pictures[indexPath.item]
    }
}

func titleForSectionAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
    if indexPath.section < sections.count {
        return sections[indexPath.section]
    }
    return nil
}


// MARK:- Private


private func loadPicturesFromDisk() -> [Picture] {
    sections.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("pictures").appendingPathExtension("plist")
    let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()

    if let retrievedPicturesData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL), let decodedPictures = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Picture>.self, from: retrievedPicturesData) {
        for picture in decodedPictures {
            let pictureName = picture.pictureName
            print("The pictureName in loadPicturesFromDisk = \(pictureName), the pictureCategory is = \(picture.pictureCategory)")
            let pictureCategory = picture.pictureCategory


            if !sections.contains(pictureCategory) {
                sections.append(pictureCategory)
            }

            let newPicture = Picture(picture: pictureName, category: pictureCategory)
            pictures.append(newPicture)

        }

        print("Enumerating through pictures in loadPicturesFromDisk")
        enumerateThroughPictures(pictures: pictures)


        return pictures

    } else {
        return []
    }
}

private func saveToFile(pictures: [Picture]) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("pictures").appendingPathExtension("plist")
    let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    let encodedPictures = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(pictures)

    try? encodedPictures?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

}

func absoluteIndexForIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    var index = 0
    for i in 0..<indexPath.section {
        index += numberOfPicturesInSection(i)
    }
    index += indexPath.item
    return index
}

private func picturesForSection(_ index: Int) -> [Picture] {
    let section = sections[index]
    let picturesInSection = pictures.filter { (picture: Picture) -> Bool in
        return picture.pictureCategory == section
    }
    return picturesInSection
}
```

}

Comment: Your code would be so much simpler and more efficient if you simply split the retrieved data into a nested array to start with, so the outer array would contain an element for each section.  The inner array would be the pictures in each section.

Comment: Point taken. I went with this model because the RW tutorials preferred this approach. I realize that does not mean the approach is smart, but those folks have good tutorials. You think this approach is pretty much doomed?

Comment: I don't know about doomed, but it seems to be much more complicated than necessary. You could probably use an `NSFetchedResultsController` with this.